# React Material-table - cannot access fields of objects (inside an array of objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've spent quite some time trying to view my fetched data in a Material-table component without success. I'm also not very familiar with JS so it is very possible that I don't see something obvious. My array of objects looks like this (it contains only 1 element, because there is only 1 patient's data to fetch from the server):

[image]

my MeterialTable:

[image]

I store fetched data in that kind of object, which I later append (push) to (at first) empty array:

[image]

But I always end up with that screen:

[image]

as if there was no data, even though I clearly have what I need (proof in console logs). At the moment I'm not sure whether there's something wrong with my data's format. I will be grateful for any ideas of fixing this issue.

Edit: This is how i store my fetched data (patients is initiated as patients = []):

[image]

and this is my columnds definition:

[image]

I also replaced my fetched data with a static random dataset with the same fields which caused data to be visible, so it would mean that there is a problem with my array of objects which stores the data.

Function that fetches and returns collected data is called and assigned here:

[image]

Comment: please add the part of the code where you store fetched data, i mean show me how you set patientsData

Comment: also please show your column definitio

Comment: @claud.io do you find these screens helpful?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are pushing your items in a `patients` array, but you are passing `patientsData` as datasource of the table

---

update: after looking at your update, i think that the problem is how you are fetching data.

you are fetching data in render function, this is not a good thing becouse every time something outside or inside your component update, then your component will retrigger the fetch function.

try mooving the fetch logic inside a componentDidMount function like:

```
componentDidMount(){
   ///1)fetch  data
   ///2)when you have data ready do be displayed set your state with the new data eg: this.setState({myPatientsStuff: patients})
}
```

then inside you render function, pass mypathientsStuff to the table source:

```
<MaterialTable  
 data={this.state.myPatientsStuff}
...etc
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure wheter that's what you meant but I'm passing patientsData (into data property of component) which contains the returned value of the function (partialy) visible above - "return patients". (I'll add another part of the code)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. It seems that this was the issue. Now I can see my data inside the table.

Comment: Unfortunately I got baited that it was the solution - development server lagged out and it kept viewing the result of me swapping my code to functional from class-based. But hey, I have a solution. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently the same code but executed as a set of functions instead of using a class fixes this issue. Looks like I don't know about something that is defined at a lower level of JS/React.